# extensionless url in IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, clean-urls, dotnetnuke-5

I have a website, which is been working on Dotnetnuke. I am using dotnetnuke's friendly url to use clean url's instead of asp's ugly QueryString urls, now my problem is, what configuration does it need for the extensionless urls in dotnetnuke using IIS7.5, i checked lots of websites on google, but could not make it, how can i use extensionless urls in asp.net, as Dotnetnuke just allows friendly urls and not extensionless urls.

I even tried using URLRewriter.net, but that too didnt helped.

How can I use extensionless url in asp.net?

Comment: ASP.NET 4.0 has URL Routing included. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using IIS URL Rewriter with the following rule:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite Tab" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([a-z0-9/]+)/tabid/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9/]+)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
<action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?tabid={R:1}"/>
</rule>    
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

This will rewrite

/Category/Subcategory/tabid/123/Default

to

/default.aspx?tabid=123

You might also be able to modify DNN's internal rewrite engine rules.

Answer (score 1):

I thought your website in 4.0 framework right??
go to iis and site application pool set to classic instead of integrated (Managed pipeline mode:).
then go to your site in IIS and open "Handler Mapping" section and add a "Wildcard Script Map..." Request path = * and Executables = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" loaproper location of this file and then restart your IIS and run your site.

I hope it will helps you....

Comment: Hi gaurav, i am using iis7 and asp.net 2.0... can you please take me to the right path for that..

Comment: @Abbas, I explain here the full way to do this.... otherwise LDAdams given URL is great to understand this...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into IIS 7's built in URL rewriter?
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/